# Reactive way to Proxy request in Spring webflux

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux

I am having a requirement in which i have to forward a request to different endpoint by adding some extra headers(usually OAuth tokens).

i tried below working one to proxying request.

```
 fun proxy(request: ServerRequest, url:String, customHeaders: HttpHeaders = HttpHeaders.EMPTY): Mono<ServerResponse> {

        val modifiedHeaders = getHeadersWithoutOrigin(request, customHeaders)

        var webClient = clientBuilder.method(request.method()!!)
                .uri(url)
        modifiedHeaders.forEach{
            val list = it.value.iterator().asSequence().toList()
            val ar:Array<String> = list.toTypedArray()
            webClient.header(it.key, *ar)
        }
        return webClient
                .body(request.bodyToMono(), DataBuffer::class.java).exchange()
                .flatMap { clientResponse ->
                    ServerResponse.status(clientResponse.statusCode())
                            .headers{
                                it.addAll(clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders())
                            }
                            .body(clientResponse.bodyToMono(), DataBuffer::class.java)
                }
    }
```

Incoming requests always hit one proxy endpoint at my server with target url in header. At server, i read target url and add OAuth tokens and forward request to target URL. In this scenario, i do not want to parse response body. Send the response as it is down stream.

What is the reactive way to do it?

Comment: maybe try to extract the body to a databuffer using the `BodyExtractor` class, and then pass this databuffer to the new webclient. And you should not create a new client on each request, that is expensive.

Comment: @Thomas, could you explain with an example